# Why would will_paginate#paginate include different objects when calling the same page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, will-paginate

After making a call to the same page different ids are returned.

```
Product.paginate(per_page: 15, page: 100).pluck(:id)
   (1.2ms)  SELECT "products"."id" FROM "products" LIMIT 15 OFFSET 1485
=> [37990, 37991, 37992, 37993, 37994, 37995, 37996, 37997, 37998, 37999, 38000, 38001, 38002, 38003, 38004]

Product.paginate(per_page: 15, page: 100).pluck(:id)
   (0.7ms)  SELECT "products"."id" FROM "products" LIMIT 15 OFFSET 1500
=> [38799, 38800, 38801, 38802, 38803, 38804, 38805, 38806, 38807, 38808, 38809, 38810, 38811, 38812, 38813]

Product.paginate(per_page: 15, page:100).pluck(:id)
   (3.0ms)  SELECT "products"."id" FROM "products" LIMIT 15 OFFSET 1485
=> [24513, 24514, 33230, 18489, 33509, 33510, 33511, 33512, 33513, 33514, 34250, 33515, 33516, 33517, 33518]
```

My Product model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible  :brand_id, :description, :name, :db_ref, :packages_attributes, :photos_attributes, :published, :alias

  # Relations
  has_many :photos
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos
  has_many :cart_items
  has_many :packages, inverse_of: :product
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :packages, allow_destroy: true
  has_many :prices, :through => :packages
  has_many :group_assignments, as: :groupable
  has_many :groups, through: :group_assignments
  belongs_to :brand
  belongs_to :business

  # Callbacks
  before_validation :inherit_business_id
  before_create :set_default_alias

  # Validations
  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_presence_of :business
  validates_uniqueness_of :name, scope: [:brand_id, :business_id, :published]
end
```

Comment: Could you post the code for `pluck`? I don't know if this is the answer, but I can think of two possibilities. First, something is being inserted into the database between the two calls. Second, the entries are not ordered by anything, so their order is not guaranteed. The order might be changing somewhere between the two searches in the first 1500 entries, causing the 1500th row to not be what was expected I would have thought you'd want `ORDER BY products.id` in that query.

Comment: Edited the question to show code that generated the SQL statements. Do you think that may have an effect on the ordering?

Comment: I don't understand the `.pluck(:id)` part.  Here is the example from [the docs](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate): `## perform a paginated query:
@posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page])

# or, use an explicit "per page" limit:
Post.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)

## render page links in the view:
<%= will_paginate @posts %>`

Comment: Very odd, since you're calling the same page (page: 100) but getting different results.  This suggests there is something happening between these two calls which is inserting/removing records.

Comment: @RustyToms .pluck is a rails4 addition which only returns the given table column from your model.

Comment: The 'pluck' part only takes the id of the objects queried. I used it to show the reader that there are product ids repeated in different pages since it is easier to see the ids than the object's string representation.

Comment: If you do 
`Product.paginate(per_page: 15, page: 100)
Product.paginate(per_page: 15, page: 101)`
does it work correctly? You are not changing the page number in your example.

Comment: Sorry edited the question to show that the same call gave two different results.

Comment: Can we see your Product model?

Comment: Also, are you absolutely SURE nothing is modifying the database between these two calls?

Comment: (I know it's very old). Did you ever discovered why this happened, besides indirect fix with sorting by id? It's really strange that paginate call with the same numeric parameters generate different SQL statements (offset 1500 and offset 1485). Also, it's really strange that two equal DB calls (first with offset 1485 and second with same offset) return different values. Although order results is not guaranteed unless specified, same query should give same records _unless_ changes to DB were made.

Comment: I used Postgres in this example. Based on the answer below I'd look at Postgres' default ordering for more specific details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a sort, and see if that resolves the issue:

```
Product.order(:id).paginate(per_page: 15, page: 100).pluck(:id)
```

What's happening is the order the results are returned from the database are not guaranteed, so they are being returned in an unknown order.  By adding a specific order, you can guarantee they will be returned the same each time.

Comment: I haven't found anything changing the database. The error stops occurring once I add an `order('id')` call before the call to paginate.

Comment: By "Error" do you mean the undefined method 'empty?' or that this resolves the original issue?

Comment: I meant the original issue.

Comment: Thing is I thought the ordering by id was default, unless you specified a default scope or something else.

Comment: Using PG, dunno if it may affect the ordering.

Comment: @cabe56 unscoped simply removes any previous scopes, it doesn't add any sorting by itself.  In your case, it may not be needed since there doesn't seem to be any scopes defined.

Comment: @cabe56 without a specific scope, there's no guarantee on the order the records are returned from the DB.

Comment: Ok, I was under the impression that there was such thing as default ordering of active record models ('id ASC')